# How to access contacts from lost phone?

Tags: contacts, lost-phone

I lost my phone and my sim card, but saved my previous contacts on my gmail account. How can I find them again.

Comment: It is totally unclear what you are asking for. Are your contacts not saved in gmail?

Comment: They should be located in https://contacts.google.com

Answer (score 1):

Contacts stored on google will automatically be synced with any new android device you log into with your google account. You just have to head over to contacts to see them.

If you don't have an android device to login with, you could head over to [Google Contacts page](http://www.google.com/contacts) to view them. Google offers the option of exporting the contacts to view them on a computer offline. You could export them and open them in excel by clicking **more** on the left tabs then export>google csv format.

**Note** Since csv files are supported by Excel, you can just click on the file and open it in Excel. If however, you come across any problems in opening it, you can solve them by importing csv file into Excel. Choose the Data tab and the From Text option.After this, the Text Import Wizard will appear. It will lead you through several steps, one of which is choosing the type of delimiter. Once you’re finished, you’ll have a list of gmail contacts in your Excel document.